# installing python-pcl module on python

Tags: python, import

I have tried to install python PCL library on my pc. I used the instructor introduced in https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl.
As it said, it has 3 requirements as follow:
1(Miniconda/Anaconda) - Python 3.5 (mine is 3.7)
2- Cython <= 0.25.2 (installed)

3-Gtk+ (installed as introduced in https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php using  MSYS2).
I don't know if it satisfies this requirement. Then I installed visual studio 2014, after that, I installed 'PCL-1.9.1-AllInOne-msvc2017-win64', and add `C:\Program Files\OpenNI2\Samples\Bin` to my system path. I even install `conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl` on my python. but when I try to `import pcl` the following error occurs:

`Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pcl\__init__.py", line 5, in <module> from ._pcl import ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to successfully install pcl on your system:

- Firstly, [download](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases/download/pcl-1.8.1/PCL-1.8.1-AllInOne-msvc2017-win64.exe) pcl and then follow the steps to set environment variables as described [here](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl181/).
- Setup a new environment with Python 3.6 and then activate that environment on command prompt.
- Run the below commands one after the other:

  1. `conda install -c sirokujira pcl --channel conda-forge`
  2. `conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl --channel conda-forge`

Comment: The link to setting up the environment variables is broken. Can you please update the link?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into similar problems. I've just managed to install python-pcl on windows 10 by following these steps:

```
-> conda create -n ipk # create a new conda env. 
-> conda activate ipk # activate env.
-> conda update -n base -c defaults conda # update conda
-> conda config --add channels conda-forge # add conda-forge channels 
-> conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl # pcl installation 
-> conda install -c jithinpr2 gtk3 # Gtk+ Gui dependency 
-> conda install -y ipython # install ipython -> conda install -y jupyter # install jupyter
```